# Compiling glibc-2.17 libraries

Tags: 12.04, make, configure, glibc

I hope you can help me.
For my class project, I'm suppose to identify and fix GHOST vulnerability in GLIBC in Ubuntu 12.04; I did that. However, the instructor doesn't want the fix by just upgrading the glibc version (by doing $apt-get upgrade.) He wants us to fix the source file and then configure it and install it. Here is what I did:

1)  I downloaded the source file from  https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libc/glibc 2.17.tar.gz and it is stored it in my /Downloads.

2) then, I did $tar xvzf glibc-2.17.tar.gz

3) then, I did $cd ~/Downloads/glibc-2.17

4) I did my edits in the ~/Downloads/glibc-2.17/nss/digits_dots file

5) then, I did $./configure

here I got an error saying
configure: error: you must configure in a separate build directory

6) So, I did $mkdir glibc-build

7) then, I did $cd ~/Downloads/glibc-build

8) then, I did $../glibc-2.17/configure

9) then, I did $make
but it said 
(make: *** no targets specified and no makefile found. stop)

I really am lost here, could someone tell me what are the next procedures, i.e. how I can configure, make, and install my edits. Please help.

Thank you

Comment: Did step 8) complete **without any errors**?

Comment: There were no errors, but there were lots of (no's) as a result of checking. I checked ~/Downloads/glibc-builds/config.log, and it checked for make and found it in /usr/bin/make

Comment: how can i upload a snapshot ?

Comment: IIRC the configure script declines to create Makefiles for the default install prefix (to stop users screwing up their systems): did you choose a different prefix, or override with `--disable-sanity-checks` (which I don't recommend, for obvious reasons)?

Comment: Sorry! I just checked again... There was a configuration error... It says:

Comment: These critical programs are missing or too old: gawk

Comment: It also says: Check the INSTALL file for required version

Comment: configure: error: 
*** These critical programs are missing or too old: gawk
*** Check the INSTALL file for required versions.

Comment: The default version of `awk` has been `mawk` for some time (not sure if that applies to 12.04) so make sure your system actually has `gawk` (i.e. `sudo apt-get install gawk`)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host?noredirect=1&lq=1